# Laravel after function parameters

Tags: laravel

I have some code

```
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {

        var_dump($request->input('answer'));

        if (true) {
            $validator->errors()->add('Question', 'The answer is not correct!');
        }
    });
```

But I'm facing the problem where I need to pass $request->input('answer') down. It gives me an error that $request is not defined. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think this is enough code for a [mcve]. For all we know, `request` _is_ undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function contact(Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'id' => 'required',
        'boat' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'answer' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required'
    ]);


   if ((int)$request->input('answer') != $request->session()->get('contact-seller-answer')) {
   }
    $validator->after(function ($validator, **$request**) {

        var_dump($request->input('answer'));

        if (true) {
            $validator->errors()->add('Question', 'The answer is not correct!');
        }
    });


    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('ad/'.$request->input('id').'/'.$request->input('boat').'#form')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput($request->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: I solve it myself. Setting the Request through $this-> makes it available in other function

http://www.marinebroker.net